# PySimpleGui: keep the previous file path in the Input file element

Tags: python, user-interface, input, pysimplegui

It is possible to to keep the previous file path entered for input files in the PySimpleGui after closing the GUI?
It means, I don’t have to browse the path again when using the GUI.

Unfortunately I did not find any example of that.

Comment: Could you please edit this question to include your code.

Comment: refer https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/#example-user-settings-usage